# android Fragment popBackStack confusion

Tags: android, fragment

I have a lot of Fragments. e.g: A1,A2,A3, B1,B2,C1,C2,C3. All Fragments were in a container,FActivity.
I hoped when current Fragment was A1 or B1 or c1 I press the back key,the project finished.
I follwed this order to hide previous one and show next one, and all of them were addToBackStack.But when I call FActivity.onBackPressed(), I found the popBack not restoring previous fragment and feel confused.some fragment were missed.Especially B1 and C1 were not in the backstack. They were missed.

here is my hide&show code:

```
   private void showFragment(FragmentTransaction ft1, Fragment fm1, Fragment fm2, String tag) {
        if (fm1 != null) {
            if (!fm1.isAdded()) {
                ft1.add(R.id.information_detail, fm1).hide(fm1);
            } else {
                ft1.hide(fm1);
            }
                ft1.addToBackStack(tag);
        }
        if (!fm2.isAdded()) {
            ft1.add(R.id.infomation_detail, fm2, tag);
        } else {
            ft1.show(fm2);
        }
        ft1.commit();
    }
```

fragment control

```
Fragment currentFragment ;
     public void startFragmentOnParameter(Fragment oldFragment, String tag, String... param) {

            FragmentTransaction ft1 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            switch (tag) {
                case "A1":
                    A1= new A1();
                    showFragment(ft1,oldFragment, A1, true, "A1");
                    currentFragment = mPatientCaseInHistory;
                    break;
                case "A2":
                    A2= new A2();
                    showFragment(ft1, oldFragment, A2, false, "A2");
                    currentFragment = mPatientWithArrear2;
                    break;
                case "A3":
                    A3= new A3();
                    showFragment(ft1, oldFragment, A3, false, "A3");
                    currentFragment = mPatientsCases3;
                    break;
               ......
}
```

and onBackPressed

```
public void onBackPressed() {

        String name = currentFragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
        if(name.equals("A1")||name.equals("B2")||name.equals("C1")){

            finish();
        }else{
            super.onBackPressed();
            currentFragment  = (Fragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.infomation_detail);
        }
    }
```

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Try removing super.onBackPressed();

Comment: @AjinkyaS If I remove super.onBackPressed(),the popBackStack() will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
```

instead

```
 super.onBackPressed();
```